# What kind of behavior should occur if a user tries to copy a value and it is not possible to copy it or returns null?

Tags: user-behavior, copy-paste

In an application I am working on when trying to copy a value sometimes there is no value that is returned and we tell the user that there is no value. However, the part I am curious about is what should happen to the clipboard?

Situation A:
Set clipboard to " " In this instance the clipboard is essentially cleared and if there was an important value in the clipboard it is lost and replaced with nothing.

Situation B:
Don't set clipboard at all and keep the whatever it was set to as just that. I think this would be nice as you might still need the previous value (the last working copy's value)

Any other ideas or standards for this?

Comment: Yes, B. — Is there a way to indicate what is copy-able and not copy-able, before the user tries to copy? That seems to me to be the primary UX issue here.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, good point. Your thinking has led to me to believe it would make more sense to grey out the ui element to copy something if the value to be copied value would be null

Comment: Depends on how the copy action fits in the process or workflow. In which case you can either prevent it, or provide enough messaging to the user to indicate what the outcome will be if they continue to try and perform the action.